# Insert duplicate value into Pandas row

Tags: python, pandas

I want to split up the Jobs, Steve. 01/31 column so that [SPGC-9456, 6.0]] is on its own row.

What my code outputs now:

```
                                             2017-01-31           2017-02-01
   Gates, Bill.                             [[SPGC-14075, 0.5]]         NaN
   Jobs, Steve.           [[SPGC-14075, 3.5], [SPGC-9456, 6.0]]         NaN
   White, John ANDERSON.  [[SPGC-14075, 1.75]]              [[SPGC-9456, 1.75]]
```

What I want:

```
                                            2017-01-31           2017-02-01
 Gates, Bill.                             [[SPGC-14075, 0.5]]         NaN
 Jobs, Steve.                           [[SPGC-14075, 3.5]            NaN
 Jobs, Steve.                             [SPGC-9456, 6.0]]           NaN                  
 White, John ANDERSON.                   [[SPGC-14075, 1.75]]  [[SPGC-9456, 1.75]]
```

Comment: You are looking for `unnest` ~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
col = '2017-01-31'
v = df[col].values.tolist()
l = [len(x) for x in v]
d = {col: [[x] for y in v for x in y]}
df.reindex(df.index.repeat(l)).assign(**d)

                                 2017-01-31           2017-02-01
Gates, Bill.            [[SPGC-14075, 0.5]]                  NaN
Jobs, Steve.            [[SPGC-14075, 3.5]]                  NaN
Jobs, Steve.             [[SPGC-9456, 6.0]]                  NaN
White, John ANDERSON.  [[SPGC-14075, 1.75]]  [[SPGC-9456, 1.75]]
```

---

**Setup**

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        [[['SPGC-14075', .5]], np.nan],
        [[['SPGC-14075', 3.5], ['SPGC-9456', 6.]], np.nan],
        [[['SPGC-14075', 1.75]], [['SPGC-9456', 1.75]]]
    ], 
    'Gates, Bill.|Jobs, Steve.|White, John ANDERSON.'.split('|'),
    ['2017-01-31', '2017-02-01']
)
```

Comment: better Than mine solution ~!!+1

Comment: That looks great. Is there any way that I could then make those SPGC- # entries as headers for columns or would I need to change my setup first? This all came from a dict called day_dict. ie. dataframe = pd.dataframe(day_dict)

Comment: @jenkelblankel best thing you could do is to ask a different question and clearly show what your starting point is, provide code to create starting point, and show what it is you'd like to see as your result.  It's difficult to answer your question as I'm unsure what you mean exactly.  You can rectify that by taking the time to ask another good question.  And you'll likely get a bit more rep (-:

Answer (score 1):

I am not using your data, you can try with my temp data.

```
Temp=pd.DataFrame({'Index':['str1', 'str2', 'str3'],'va':[['x'],[['y'],['z']],['z']],'va2':[np.nan,np.nan,['YY']]}).set_index('Index')
Temp_unnest = pd.DataFrame([[i, x]
              for i, y in Temp['va'].apply(list).iteritems()
                  for x in y], columns=list('IV'))
Temp_unnest['va2']=Temp_unnest.I.map(Temp.va2)
Temp_unnest.set_index('I',inplace=True)
Temp_unnest.columns=Temp.columns

Temp_unnest
Out[121]: 
       va   va2
I              
str1    x   NaN
str2  [y]   NaN
str2  [z]   NaN
str3    z  [YY]
```